# Extension of a von Neumann algebra by a von Neumann algebra

Tags: measure-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I asked [this question at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003201/extension-of-a-von-neumann-algebra-by-a-von-neumann-algebra) now I repeat it at MO:

Let  $A,B,C$ be  $3$ unital  $C^*$ algebras.  Assume  that  we  have  the  following  short  exact sequence  of $C^*$-algebras:

$$0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$$

Assume  that $A,B$  are  generated by their projections. Is $C$  necessarily  generated by its  projections, too?

> Assume  that $A,B$  are  von Neumann  algebras, is $C$  necessarily a  von  Neumann  algebra, too?

Does  the  last  question has  an obvious  answer  when $A,B$ (hence $C$) are  commutative  algebras?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. Let $C$ be a C*-algebra and let $A \subseteq C$ be an ideal which is intrinsically a von Neumann algebra. Then the positive part of the unit ball of $A$ has a least upper bound in $A$ which must be a projection. (Its norm cannot be greater than $1$, so if it is not a projection then its square root also belongs to the unit ball and is larger.) It follows that $C \cong A \oplus B$, so if $B$ is also intrinsically a von Neumann algebra then so is $C$.

Comment: Thank  you and  +1 for  your  interesting answer. i  confess that I did not pay  attention to the fact that the  extension is  trivial if the  first object, $A$ ,  is  unital. I  am  quite  beginner in this  area and  also  in von Neumann  algebra.

Comment: You're welcome! See the edit history of my post for an answer to a similar question where we assume $A$ and $C$ are com Neumann algebras.

Answer (score 6):

This is an extended comment on Nik Weaver's nice answer.  (Unless I've made a mistake, this argument shows that $A$ being unital does all the work).

What exactly do we mean by
$$ 0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0 $$
is an exact sequence of $C^*$-algebras?  I think what is meant is that we have $*$-homomorphisms
$$ \phi : A\rightarrow C, \qquad \psi :C\rightarrow B, $$
with $\phi$ injective, $\psi$ surjective, and $\ker\psi = \operatorname{im}\phi$.  We do *not* assume that $\phi$ or $\psi$ is unital.

However, in the original question, we do assume that $A,B,C$ are unital.  Let $p=\phi(1)\in C$ so that $p=p^2=p^*$ as $\phi$ is a $*$-homomorphism.  So $p$ is a projection, so also $1-p$ is a projection.  Also $p\phi(a) = \phi(a)p$ for all $a\in A$.

As $\phi(A) = \ker\psi$ is an ideal in $C$, if $c\in C$ with $pc=c$ (or $cp=c$) then $c\in \phi(A)$.  So $\phi(A) = \{ c\in C: cp=c \}$.   Further, for any $c\in C$, we see that $pc=c$ if and only if $c=cp$.  So, for any $c\in C$, we have that $pc=pcp$ and $cp=pcp$.  For $c\in C$ let $d=(1-p)c$ so $0 = pd = dp$ so $d(1-p)=d$ so $(1-p)c=(1-p)c(1-p)$.

Define
$$ B' = \{ c\in C : cp=pc=0 \} = \{c\in C: c(1-p)=(1-p)c=c\}. $$
Then $B'$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $C$.  If $c\in B'$ with $\psi(c)=0$ then $c=\phi(a)$ for some $a\in A$ so $cp=c=0$.  So $\psi$ is injective on $B'$.  For any $c\in C$, 
$$ c = pc + (1-p)c = pcp + (1-p)c(1-p), $$
from the discussion above.  Then $pcp\in \phi(A)$ and $c'=(1-p)c(1-p)\in B'$ so $\psi(c) = \psi(c')$.  So $\psi$ restricts to a $*$-isomorphism between $B'$ and $B$.

We have hence carefully shown that $C$ is isomorphic to $A\oplus B$.

It now immediately follows that if $A,B$ are generated by their projections, then so is $C$; if $A,B$ are von Neumann algebras, then so is $C$.

Comment: Good answer. I wasn't assuming they had units, but of course you're right, if $A$ is intrinsically a von Neumann algebra then it has to have one.

Comment: Thank  you and  +1 for  your  interesting answer. i  confess that I did not pay  attention to the fact that the  extension is  trivial if the  first object, $A$ ,  is  unital. I  am  quite  beginner in this  area and  also  in von Neumann  algebra.